# How to push shared files (header/source) from outside a Git repository to it?

Tags: linux, git, header-files

I've developed two small programs, both of which include `my_lcd_lib.h` and `my_lcd_lib.c`.
To prevent code duplication I moved this "lib" from the include folder in each project to `/usr/local/include`. So far, so good.

How could I tell Git to include those files when pushing the repo?
So the repos from Prog1 and Prog2 would have their own copies of the header/source files.

I can imagine three ways:

1. When pushing the program repo from dev pc to gitlab server, git could include those outside files by some tricks. Maybe need to edit some `.git*` files?
2. I could make a lib-repo for the stuff in `/usr/local/include`. I could set up my program repo to load the appropriate files from the lib-repo. Is that what the pipe/cli are meant for?
3. I could copy the header files from `/usr/local/include` to the program repo just before pushing the program repo. This looks very unsexy.

Comment: You can probably do something with [Git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), but you have it backwards. Git is not a release, build, nor installation tool. Add the files in your Git repository and install them into `/usr/local/include` using your normal build and install process.

Comment: Have you tried the symbol link? use `ln -s /usr/local/include include`.

Comment: i think i did my question from the wrong direction. How do you handle headers that are used by 2 or more projects (repos). You don't want to have serveral copies from the headers (if it is still in development). But the Repos need the headers for future install process on live systems. symlink is committed to this? I never touched symlink before

Comment: Your second way is what I would do. A separate library repo.

Comment: thx, but i only the know the first half of this way. How i tell my programm1 repo that it should grap some file from another? And how this been triggered?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot push files outside the repository. Git does not push individual files, it pushes commits. The files have to part of a commit.

Once you've committed those files in your repository, the rough solution is to [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) them into `/usr/local/include/`. The better solution is to used a build tool like [`autoconf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html) and install them in `/usr/local/include`.

Git is not a substitute for a build tool, nor dependency manager, nor installer.